# Incompatible signatures when spawning thread with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkitem

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

The error is:

> Method 'Private Sub ProcessToolWork()'
>   does not have a signature compatible
>   with delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   WaitCallback(state As Object)'.

What's the deal here? I've never experienced this error spawning a thread in this fashion.

Here are my routine definitions:

```
Public Sub ProcessWork()
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ProcessToolWork)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessToolWork()

End Sub
```

See anything wrong?

I've also tried making a new WaitCallback for this item like so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf ProcessToolWork))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) takes a `state` argument (of type `Object`). Even if you ignore it, you have to put it in your method signature:

```
Private Sub ProcessToolWork(ByVal ignored As Object)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this only necessary with Options Explicit turned on?

Comment: I don't know - but I *suspect* that with Option Explicit off it would just fail at execution time instead.

Comment: Huh. I'm vexed. In a previous project I queued a thread successfully in this fashion:

Private Sub m_btnCollectData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles m_btnCollectData.Click
  Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf DoDataCollector)
End Sub

Private Sub DoDataCollector()
 'stuff
End Sub

The difference being that it was a web application.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. Sounds like a bad idea to not implement the right signature though.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same thing myself.  Just before doing a "final" compile, I turned Option Strict to "on", and this error appeared.

Note: That's Option Strict, not Option Explicit.

So, it's only necessary to provide the "Byval ignored As Object" parameter if you are trying to compile with Option Strict on.